# what is STT_FUNC type in assemblly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have following code of assemblly. but i can not understand what is STT_FUNC ??

```
.section .rodata
    Lhello:
        .asciz "Hello!"

.section .text
        .globl function1
        .type function1, STT_FUNC
function1:
```

Comment: That looks like GNU `as`. Have you tried to read [the documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/)?

Comment: What about this question is C? Please clarify or delete the tag.

Comment: What platform and object-file format was your compiler targeting when it made this?

Comment: for x86-64 architecture and elf file format

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Type.html), the directive

```
.type function1,STT_FUNC
```

also written

```
.type function1,@function
```

marks the symbol `function1` as having *symbol type* `STT_FUNC`. This makes a difference when linking dynamically as PLT entries are generated for functions only.

It is generally a good idea to mark your symbol appropriately: Mark symbols referring to data as

```
.type some_variable,@object
```

and symbols referring to functions as

```
.type some_function,@function
```

Comment: Ah, I'd always wondered what symbol-type info was for other than debugging.

Comment: what is PLT? It'd be nice if you could give more context.  Thanks

Comment: @LucasZanella See [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1992) for an introduction.